# How to allow ASP.NET Core web request to complete but still run SignalR update function in the background

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, signalr

I have certain API request in our controllers which updates our database and then a signalR hub set up such that when this API request is run then our javascript frontend also is called to make the clients also initiate a new request to update the data on their frontend:

```cs
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> TakeControl([FromForm] string jsonData)
    {

        String query = "exec dbo.A2P_0138_TakeControl_QA @jsonData, @UserID";

        using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            var queryResult = connection.Query(query, new { jsonData = jsonData, UserID = UserID });

            await hubContext.Clients.All.SendAsync("UpdateDashboard");

            return Ok(new { Result = "Success" });

        }

    }
```

My issue is the SendAsync is actually pretty slow when updating all users as we have about 20 of them. I would actually like it if I could remove the async and actually let the web request finish and and not away SendAsync but still let that small bit run on the web server. Is that possible? Would I need to utilize Task.Run()? Not sure if this is bad practice or not as well.

Answer (score 0):

> I would actually like it if I could remove the async and actually let the web request finish and and not away SendAsync but still let that small bit run on the web server. Is that possible? Would I need to utlize Task.Run()? Not sure if this is bad practice or not as well

In my opinion, without using the Async to with the send method, it still slow since the thread will wait for the send's result, also using the Task.Run() to start the new task also not make sense, if the update request volume is very high, it will create so many taks and make your application doesn't work.

Normally, for this kind of scenario, we will use service bus queue(like rabbitMQ) to achieve it, you could write a background worker service which contain the trigger for the service bus, if it contains the update(when the api excuted, it will add one recode to the service bus) and then update the front-end by using the sendasync inside the worker service. At the same time, you could decide how often the front-end update since it very slow.